# Adding get and set methods for increment_id of customer_entity table

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer, extension-attributes

How to add get and set methods for increment_id of `customer_entity` table in magento2.

i have added in `extension_attribute` and added plugin for `customerinterface` class but it is not effecting core file

Comment: Sorry, donot understand your word,Magento using Primary key  `entity_id`  for table `customer_entity`  .

Comment: i want to add getincrementId() and setIncrementId() in customerInterface class,how to add